# Java Initialize an array with numbers

Tags: java

> 6, 9
>
> 2, 5
>
> 4, 6

how to initialize these number in an 2D array?

this is my answer, but something with output.

```
int[][] num = new int [3][2];

    num[0][0] = 6;
    num[0][1] = 9;
    num[1][0] = 2;
    num[1][1] = 5;
    num[2][0] = 4;
    num[2][1] = 6;

System.out.println(num);
```

> [[I@70f87478   (output)

Answer (score 5):

There's nothing wrong with that output, other than you're calling `toString` on array and expecting to get something useful. If you use [`Arrays.deepToString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepToString%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29) instead, you'll get a more sensible result. (You'd normally only need `Arrays.toString()`, but you need the "deep" version as it's an array of arrays.)

Additionally, you can initialize the array more compactly. Combining the two:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] num = { { 6, 9 }, { 2, 5 }, { 4, 6 } };
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(num));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[[6, 9], [2, 5], [4, 6]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int[][] num = {{6,9},{2,5},{4,6}}
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(num));
```

Answer (score 0):

Logic like in `deepToString`

```
        int [][] test = new int[1][1];
        StringBuilder builder  = new StringBuilder();
        for (int[] ints : test) {
           builder.append(Arrays.toString(ints)); 
        }
        System.out.println(builder.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do

```
System.out.println(num);
```

You will print the object's default ´toString` method, which prints the object's reference. TO print the contents, you can use 2 nested for-loops or a for-each loop.